# Cordova: Implicit pending intent vulnerability

Tags: android, cordova, android-pendingintent, android-security

We have a mobile app built using Cordova and we are getting following warning in Google Play Console since we upgraded `cordova-android` to `12.0.1` -

[image]

We scanned all the plugins we are using and can confirm that they have correctly implemented `PendingIntent`. We are having a hard time figuring out where else could this issue be.

Any suggestions in this regard would be of great help.